# Google Custom Search - Add Numbering to results

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I wonder if its possible to add numbering to the results returned by the google custom search and output it to the right of the text like this:

First Result 1

Second Result 2

Third Result 3

What would be the best way to go about this ?

EDIT

This is the code i'm currently using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('search', '1');
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
        var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl(
        'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
        customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
        var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
        options.enableSearchResultsOnly();
        customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
        function parseParamsFromUrl() {
            var params = {};
            var parts = window.location.search.substr(1).split('\x26');
            for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                var keyValuePair = parts[i].split('=');
                var key = decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[0]);
                params[key] = keyValuePair[1] ?
                decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ')) :
                keyValuePair[1];
            }
            return params;
        }
        var urlParams = parseParamsFromUrl();
        var queryParamName = "s";
        if (urlParams[queryParamName]) {
            customSearchControl.execute(urlParams[queryParamName]);
        }
    }, true);
</script>
```

Comment: we would like to see some code

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use a ordered list  tag